# routeSettings from Navigator to MaterialApp flutter

Tags: routes, flutter, navigator

is there any way to get access from Navigator class (super...super child) to MaterialApp ?

```
child: Navigator(
              onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings){
                print('settings ${settings.name}');
                if(settings.name == '/'){
                  return MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (_) => _page(index),
                      settings: settings
                  );
                }
                else if(settings.name == '/blog_details'){
                  return CustomRoute<bool>(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => BlogDetailsPage(widget.model)
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
```

from above code to below

```
child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: getAdaptiveThemeData(context),
          routes: { /// some routes///}
          onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings){
            if(settings.name == '/blog_details'){
              return CustomRoute<bool>(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => BlogDetailsPage(_model)
              );
            }
          },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access your MaterialApp navigator with [rootNavigator: true](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/of.html),

```
FlatButton(
   child: Text('Push App Route'),
   onPressed: () {
     Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
         .pushNamed('/blog_details');
   },
)
```